# What does "She ran up the stairs two at a time." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> **[at a time](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/time_1#time_idmg_9)**
>
> ​separately or in groups of two, three, etc. on each occasion
>
> *We had to go and see the principal one at a time.*
>
> *She ran up the stairs two at a time.*
>
> *He surfs the internet for hours at a time.*

---

When we said "**She ran up the stairs two at a time.**", it could be

- There were a group of children for example playing running up the stairs.
- They divided into many groups of two.
- Each group ran up the stairs at a time.
- **She** & her friend ran up the stairs together.

**Do I understand it correctly?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As it says "She ..." we are talking about one girl, and not a group of girls.

So it can't mean that there was a group that divided into pairs and each pair ran together.

Instead it means that she took two steps of the stairs in one stride.  Normally you tread on each step of the stairs. If you are running you might go over two steps. This is what is meant by "two at a time". It means two steps, not two girls.

If you said

> They ran up the steps two at a time.

The sentence is ambiguous. But ambiguous is not always bad. In context it would be understood and it avoids the repetition of  "They ran up the steps two steps at a time."

Native speakers generally don't use any more words than they need to. Talking about 'treads' or 'risers' is too formal and unnecessary. These words are used by builders and people who make, repair, or install stairs.

Comment: why don't they say "She ran up the stairs two treads / risers at a time"?

Comment: Native speakers generally don't use any more words than they need to. Talking about 'treads' or 'risers' is too formal and unnecessary. These words are used by builders and people who make, repair, or install stairs.

Comment: To describe a person ascending or descending stairs in a hurry, we can say e.g. 'she _took the stairs_ two at a time'.

Comment: @Tom why would you? Firstly 'treads' and 'risers' aren't the terms for stairs, but for parts of a stair; you'd have trouble running up risers as they are the vertical parts.  Also, just like you wouldn't say 'She ate the sweets two sweets at a time' as it is excessively repetitive, so 'She run up the stairs two stairs at a time' becomes 'She run up the stairs two at a time" as the singular stair is also one step of a staircase.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey is right, there's a phrasing that isn't ambiguous and "we" native speakers are wont to use it. To indicate the other meaning we have "They went in pairs up the stairs", and other such rhymes.

Comment: @Tom: The most common word for a single step in a staircase is simply "stair". You could say "She ran up the stairs two stairs at a time." But that sounds quite repetitive, so the second "stairs" is usually omitted. We're already talking about the stairs, and they're the only plural thing mentioned, so it should be fairly clear (at least to native/fluent speakers) that that's what the number "two" is referring to. It's fundamentally no different from, say, "She picked up the apples two at a time," where it's also clear that "two" refers to "apples".

Comment: I don't agree that "*They ran up the steps two at a time.*" is ambiguous.  To me this still says unambiguously that two (or more) people are running up stairs skipping every other step.  Sure it *could* be interpreted the other way, but most English speakers wouldn't, since the fact there's more than one person is already implied by "they", so it'd be redundant.  If you wanted to say they were running in pairs, you'd more likely just explicitly say "*They ran up the stairs in pairs.*"

Comment: @Tom "treads" or "risers" are the wrong words and would not be understood. You can certainly say "two steps at a time" if you want to be explicit, but it's not necessary.

Comment: To my ear, using the phrase "go up the steps" would very strongly imply that the steps were regarded as individual units, while "go up the stairs", would imply that all of the steps or staircases should be treated as a single collective noun.  For one person to "go up the stairs two at a time" would strike me as odd English usage; more typical would be "go up the steps two at a time".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: As a USA native I've certainly used the term "stair" used as a singular, but not nearly as often as "step".  If one were to say "A handrail is not needed for landings that are at most three steps above the ground", that would be regarded as much clearer than "...three stairs above the ground".

Comment: @supercat Agreed. _Stair_ primarily means ‘flight of stairs’ to me, and ‘two stairs at a time’ would first and foremost mean ‘two flights of stairs at a time’ (which obviously wouldn’t work for running, unless you’re a seriously impressive jumper). “She went up the stairs two steps at a time” is perfectly natural, however, and probably how I would say it in practice.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yeah, the best I've managed as a sprinty move, in my younger (and probably stupider) days, was descending a building with two flights per floor, one flight at a time (jump from the landing to the midpoint of each flight, and from there to the next landing, with a very tight grip on the handrail to spin me around 180 degrees down the next flight).  I can't imagine what would have propelled me to do something that crazy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's one of those things that depends on usage.  Sometimes you use stair and step completely interchangeably.  "Two stairs at a time" would be understood by nearly everyone as talking about steps because it's a common phrase and it wouldn't make any sense at all to be taking about flights of stairs that way. "How many stairs are there" however, would often be answered in terms of flights, because that's the most relevant unit once the number of stairs gets large.  As common in English the context of how the word is used makes the meaning clear.

Comment: Let's go one step further ... "They took the stairs two at a time" They, single or plural? At a time, which noun?  And now took, acquiring or ascending?

Answer (score 20):

It's a singular "she", so it's not about pairs or groups of children running.  "Two at a time" refers to the stairs.  She is skipping alternating steps, ascending two steps with each stride.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that she took two steps at a time. To better visualise it she skipped one step each time she took a stride.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence strikes me as atypical English usage.  A more typical way of writing it would be "She ran up the *steps* two at a time", meaning that she ascended two steps with each stride.  Although "stair" can be used as a singular noun, the word "step" is used far more often for that purpose.  If someone goes "up the stairs" from the first to the second floor, it would generally mean that they ascended either a staircase or two staircases connected by a landing, but that the details of the staircase(s) aren't of interest to the writer and shouldn't be of interest to the reader.  By contrast, saying "up the steps" would suggest that the steps themselves of interest.  Adding the phrase "two at a time" would make clear why.

Comment: Where are you from?  Your expectation is very different from mine (southern England), where ‘steps’ wouldn't normally refer to a staircase — not a domestic one, at least.  (You'd be more likely to use it for a few steps up from the pavement to the front door.)  Conversely, ‘going up (or down) stairs two at a time’ would be a very common and natural way to refer to someone going between storeys as fast as they could.

Comment: Sorry--I should have specified American English (midwest)

Comment: I wouldn't normally say "ran up the steps" *unless* I was trying to call attention to the individual steps within the staircase.

Comment: @gidds: Further, I'd probably do something to establish the existence of the staircase, e.g. "She ran over to the stairs, looked around, and then ran up the steps two at a time".  I guess in the context of this question I was naturally already thinking about the staircase, but if nothing had introduced the concept of "stair" or "staircase" I would mention it before mentioning the steps.

Comment: I don't think so, at least in American English.  You'd say "ran up the stairs" if it was a staircase, but "ran up the steps" if it was a broad set of steps, such as might be found in front of public buildings.

Comment: @jamesqf seems interchangable in my view.  I don't think most people have such a narrow interpretation of what stair or step means

Comment: @eps: Certainly I'd have no difficulty understanding either form, but my own inclination would be to mention the term "stair", "stairs", "staircase", etc. to establish context, and then use the term "steps" to describe what was taken "two at a time".

Comment: I'm also midwestern, and while I understand the reason for your distinction, I would never consider it wrong to refer to stairs individually—informal at worst, but perfectly common.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you: To my "ear" the phrase "two at a time" binds rather loosely with "stairs"; it would thus be attached only if no other binding is possible.  In the sentence "____ took the stairs two at a time", one would have to know what was in the ___ to know whether the phrase "two at a time" was applicable to the stairs or to the ___.  By contast, " ___ sprinted down the stairs, taking the steps two at a time" or perhaps better yet " ___ went up the stairs, two steps at a time" would be unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The singular "time" here means one occurrence or event or "occasion" as Oxford mentions. "At a time" means "during each event." There may be some ambiguity in certain cases as others have pointed out, but the main idea can generally be determined from the context. If I take my pills four at a time, that could mean I'm swallowing all four pills in one gulp or it could mean I'm swallowing one pill and then immediately swallowing the next pill after it and so on but the main idea is that I'm not spreading the pills out through the day (meaning I'm not taking two in the morning and two at night for example).

*We had to go and see the principal one at a time.* In this case one "time" is one session with the principal. No two students were seeing the principal simultaneously. Each talk with the principal involved only one student.

*He surfs the internet for hours at a time.* Similarly, a "time" here is an Internet session. Rather than using the Internet for just a few minutes before going to do something else, he spends consecutive hours on the Internet between each break.

*She ran up the stairs two at a time.* Like others have said, each "time" is each stride/step she takes. So during each stride (each occurrence of either foot landing) she will ascend two stair steps instead of one. This isn't ambiguous in terms of how many people are involved because "she" is singular, but the terms we use like "stair" and "step" can be ambiguous. "Stair" can mean a whole flight of stairs but we know it means a single step in this case and I've said "stair step" to be extra clear. "Step" is also ambiguous because it can mean a single stair step in a staircase or it can refer to the action of stepping as in "take a step forward" but I've tried to be clear in my meaning.

Comment: Kyle, a very informative comment! Nevertheless, could you be so kind to clarify your message by taking out some things not related to the word "time" (maybe, about ambiguities)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andrew. By calling this a comment, do you mean to imply that it was not appropriate to post it as an answer? Also, I'm happy to edit it for clarity but can you explain more about why removing the section about ambiguities would help? The original question was not just about time. It was specifically about the whole phrase "She ran up the stairs two at a time" which involves stairs.

Comment: Kyle, I have mistyped, that's an appropriate answer! I just wanted to mention that such kind of solution is very detailed though can be quite complex for understanding to Tom, who asked this question. I am not imposing, it is up to you. Thanks for understanding!