# Is the "When we said ..., it could be" a hypothesis? Is it necessary?

Tags: word-usage

An ELL [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241214/109190) asks about the meaning of the sentence "She ran up the stairs two at a time" this way

> When we said "She ran up the stairs two at a time.", it could be ...

I guess "When we said" used here is meant to be a sign of hypothesis. But is it necessary to use hypothesis? How about a simpler one?

> When we say ..., we might mean ...

or

> Does the sentence ... mean ...

Is the original one more fancier?

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought to answer yes, however "When we (verb)" is actually not a hypothesis or theory (which are deliberate ideas or notions about something).

"When we" is an assumptive declaration. Meaning the speaker assumes everyone does (verb)..  A better way to possibly phrase it would be "When people (verb)..." "When it is (past tense verb)...", which is still an assumption the speaker is making.

Comment: Thank you. Is the word "theory" in your answer an alternative to "hypothesis"?

Comment: At second look I am editing my answer because I have an improvement. and these comments will no longer apply.

Comment: If its the answer you accept remember to give it that check mark, so others can know it has been resolved.

Comment: I really appreciate your work and I guess that would be better to give an positive example of hypothesis. In other words, is it possible to have it to be a hypothesis by making a few modification to the example in my OP?

Comment: Note that this answer is correct when using the *present* tense ("When we say").  When using a *past* tense ("When we said"), it generally refers to the time of a specific past event (we said that in the past, and at the time we said that, the following was true), and is not an assumptive declaration.