# Is the sentence "To better visualize it she skipped one step each time she took a stride" grammatically correct or not?

Tags: grammar

An answerer [explains](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/241291/109190) a sentence "She ran up the stairs two at a time" this way

> It simply means that she took two steps at a time. **To better visualise it** she skipped one step each time she took a stride.

I could have said

> To better visualize it, **you could say**, she ...

Because the remaining part seems to be a clause, which usually follows "it means that".

Is my understanding right? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fermichem Thank you. I updated that.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. There should at least be a comma before _she_.